# MVC - How to back to previous page without refresh the textbox into blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am using `ASP.NET MVC` to develop my website, however now I am doing my registration page. I do a `POST` to my action method and I want to check whether the email is still valid. If the email is not valid, the action returns the view again, but the form is reset (all form data is gone). How can I keep the form data without refresh?

Comment: use ajax for posting the form

Comment: post your code so that you may get right answer

Comment: Show us yoiur code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a model like this:

```
public class RegistrationModel
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public int Email { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}
```

Then when the person requests the registration page, you will serve the page using an action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var model = new RegistrationModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Your view needs to accept that model. Then the view (page) will be sent to the browser. The user will fill it out and send it back by submitting the form so you need another action to handle the submission. That action may look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegistrationModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // model is valid so do whatever you need to
    // such as saving to db etc.

    // Here do a redirect to some other page
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

See in the above action, if the model is not valid, it sends the model to the view. The model has the email the user had entered so it will render it in the textbox and then send it back to the user.

**EDIT**

I added `[EmailAddress]` attribute to the model. To use it make sure you import the namespace [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute.aspx). There are many other attributes you can use such as `[Required]` etc. The full list is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: it sound a good idea, however, how do i trigger the modelstate invalid?

Comment: is it?? i connect to db and check against db if the email validity? and if not valid back to the view?

Comment: Depends what you mean by a valid email. Do you have email addresses in your database for all new users? Most likely not so all you can do is check if the format is valid. Most sites when you register send an email to that address with a link to confirm their email address. For simple email validation see my edit.

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` depends on the model state passed to controller action method, and validation attribute marked on each properties (required, regex validation etc.). You may add these attributes on `Email` property: `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` and `[RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,3})$")]` to automatically trigger email validation.

Comment: i want to check if the email existed in the database or not

Comment: You may use a data context to map DB objects and execute this LINQ query e.g.: `var isvalid = RegistrationContext.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmailAddress == model.EmailAddress)`, or use a stored procedure with SQL connection. If the email has already exist in DB just return the view with error, otherwise proceed to finish.